# How do i deploy/publish as single .cs file in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a live ASP.NET MVC app, but i have made changes to a class (and a lot of others throughout the app). I want to publish just this one class (not others as they will require database changes). How do I publish/deploy this **one** class to the live app ?

The app is hosted on IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't publish/deploy classes... You deploy assemblies.

Comment: you don't. .cs files are compiled into a dll.  you would deploy the entire dll.  If you are using source control you could go back in time to a point where you didn't make breaking (db) changes grab the source at that point.  make you change to the 1 cs file and compile and you should ok.  but you still need to deploy a full dll.

Comment: If you share your project layout we can help you compile the right DLL.